# postgres how to rewrite merge statement using INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-merge

I got Merge statement in Oracle (migrating to EDB Postgres), but unfortunately, EDB postgres doesn't support merge statement.

So how to rewrite below merge statement using INSERT and UPDATE.

```
BEGIN

        Merge into sds_dia_error_per_min_data using dual
        on (sde_date = in_date and sde_inst_name = in_inst_name
        and sde_interface_name = in_interface_name and sde_command_code = in_command_code and sde_result_code = in_result_code)
        when matched then
        update set
        sde_error_sent = sde_error_sent + in_error_sent,
        sde_error_received = sde_error_received + in_error_received
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        Insert (sde_date,sde_inst_name,sde_interface_name,sde_command_code,sde_result_code,sde_error_sent,
        sde_error_received)
        values
        (in_date,in_inst_name,in_interface_name,
        in_command_code,in_result_code,in_error_sent,
        in_error_received);

        out_status := 0 ;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/17267423#17267423

Comment: The question is unclear while you don't specify your exact version of Postgres.

Comment: it's EnterpriseDB postgres 9.6, just wanted to convert above merge statement into INSERT and UPDATE